# Doubt about existence of 4 complex roots of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

> The polynomial $x^{4}+ax^{3}+bx^{2}-32x$ where a and b are real numbers, has roots that form a square in the complex plane. Compute the area of this square.

---

In this problem, it says that the polynomial $x^{4}+ax^{3}+bx^{2}-32x$ it has roots which create a square in complex plane, but the polynomial has $0$ as one of its root, so it has another real root. So it can only have 2 complex roots on the complex plane, but then how would it create a square with only 2 points?

Comment: Are you confusing _complex plane_ with complex numbers that are not real? Real numbers (or geometrically, the real line) are part of the complex plane, so you have two real roots and two conjugate non-real roots, which are all on the complex plane, that form a square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real line is part of the complex plane.

Comment: So two of the roots are collinear with the origin point of the complex plane? (As the lie on real axis)

Comment: First of all the problem is incorrect as you can take a=1000000,b=0 and then you will have 3 different real roots. Also I recommand you read the definition of the complex plane and the complex line.

Comment: @agent_cracker103 I think the question is meant to say “for _some_ $a$ and $b$ that are unknown”, instead of for all $a$ and $b$.

Comment: It must have zero as a root, and it must have another real number as a root, and all the non-real roots have to come in conjugate pairs, so to be a square you'll need the roots to be of the form $0, d(1+i), d(1-i), \sqrt{2}d$ for some real number d

Comment: @zaemon_23 If I understand what’s you’re saying correctly, no, that’s not what happens. If any three roots of the four are collinear, how can they form a square?

Comment: why would three roots be collinear?

Comment: $-2 \sqrt(2) d^3 x + 2 \sqrt(2) d^2 x^2 + 2 d^2 x^2 - \sqrt(2) d x^3 - 2 d x^3 + x^4 = x^4+ax^3+bx^2−32x$. so $d=2^{\frac{7}{6}}$ and $x^4 - 2\cdot2^{2/3} x^3 - 4\cdot2^{1/6} x^3 + 8\cdot2^{5/6} x^2 + 8\cdot2^{1/3} x^2 - 32 x$ is the polynomial

Comment: @zaemon_23 It's unclear what you meant by "collinear with the origin point". I guess you mean zero when you say "origin point", but then one of the real roots **is** the origin point, because $x=0$ is a root.

Comment: @LawrenceD'Anna Perhaps you want $0, d(1\pm i), 2d$ as the roots, as the side of the square would be $|d(1\pm i)| = \sqrt2 |d|$ and hence its diagonal is $2|d|$.